# The Windows 10 OpenVPN client cannot connect to the server

Tags: windows, openvpn

When trying to connect, an error appears:

```
I'm trying to parse 'path/openvpn.ovpn' as an --option parameter, but I don't see a leading '--' ".
```

How do fix this?

I tried to upgrade to an older version (I have 2.6 installed) and it didn't help.

My client config:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote ip port
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name crypt_j619a9d0-68d3-42x0-8d76-82e6bbe654bf name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
verb 3
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshots of the exact error, copy and paste the exact error for us, and properly format the configuration file?  You shoud [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Also please add the exact command you use to start the client

Comment: Thanks for the answers. The problem was solved by running the application as an administrator.